# Default values for objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Javascript Code

```
var a = {};
a.test += 1; //NaN
++a.test; //NaN
```

Instead

```
var a = {};
a.test = 0;
++a.test; //1
a.test += 1; //2
```

I wonder if there could be anyway that can make first code sample work the same as second, i.e without an explicit assignment to 0. As in assigning default value for any property of an object to 0 instead `undefined`. I'm trying to do this in node.js. So, no problem of cross browser things and old ECMA Specs.

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i<10; i++) {
   if(a.test) {
     ++a.test;
   } else {
     a.test = 0;
     ++a.test;
   }
   //a.test = a.test || 0; (1)
   //++a.test;
}
```

If it is possible then the inner if/else or the assignment statement(1) in the above code can be eliminated.

Comment: Any reason you can't simply use `var a = {test: 0};`?

Comment: @outis properties are dynamically generated. You can even consider var a = []; a[0]++; Here size of the array can't be determined upfront

Comment: what should happen if `a.test === false` or `""`? it would be safer to do a.hasOwnProperty("test") if you are trying to establish whether or not the property is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this for any arbitrary undefined property.

For a *known* property name, there *is* a way, but **DO NOT USE IT !!** <sup>1</sup>

```
Object.prototype.test = 0;
```

This will give *every* object an implicit `.test` property with that value in it, and the first time you attempt to modify it the result will be stored in your own object:

```
> Object.prototype.test = 0
> a = {}
> a.test++
> a.test
1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Adding stuff to `Object.prototype` will break stuff, including `for (key in obj)`

Answer (score 4):

Javascript by default defines all new variables as undefined ( if not explicitly defined ) , which is different from Number object, which you are trying to define. So you should use smth like :

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    a.test = a.test || 0;
    ++a.test
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned ur answer in my code only. See the comment in the 3rd code snippet

Comment: You should use prototype/class object if you want your default a.test always defined, as I mention if something isn't defined explicitly as Number, String, etc. it is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is where prototypes come in useful in javascript:

```
function Demo() {
}
Demo.prototype.x = 0;
```

```
> a = new Demo();
> a.x += 1
> a.x
1
```

```
> b = new Demo()
> b.x
0
```

Comment: @mihai yup, just like my answer, since there's _no way do it if you don't know the name of the property_

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you can't. Any number added to a non-number or NaN value will always result in `NaN`

```
var a = {};
a.test += 1; // undefined + 1 = NaN
++a.test;    // ++(undefined) = NaN
```

as for the inner `if`

```
for(i = 0; i<10; i++) {
   a.test = a.test || 0; //use existing value, or if undefined, 0
   ++a.test;             //increment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
var a = {"test":0};
a.test += 1;
```

Comment: OP does not want to explicitly declare/initialize test

Answer (score -1):

Using standard JS it's not possible to do what you're asking. Unless you prototype I guess? But I'm not experienced with Prototype.And I don't think prototyping works with Node.js

The reason for this is because js is not a typed language (i.e. we only use var to declare a variable, not int a or string b), so in order to use the ++ operator, the variable needs to be given a type through assignment.

hope that helps